# android studio how to access Wi-Fi?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

android studio how to access Wi-Fi? It means that there is a list of all Wi-Fi and you click on one of them and it gives me a password. Is it possible to do this?

I searched for a lot of information, but I didn't find anything intelligible. Help me if it's even possible to do it) If you ask why I need this, then for knowledge about android and java in general, I want something new, interesting))) In general, if it is really possible to do this, then I would like to know how to do it.

Comment: It's impossible to get wi-fi password from android device. It would be a big security issue then.

Comment: I do not know what are you trying to do but it seems like you are trying to breach security